# How to control Android Emulator from Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, emulation

I am looking for Gradle plugin to control Android emulator.
Functionality I need from it is:

starting/stopping

install/uninstall

running connected tests

And preferably auto creation and setup (including download if missing) of Emulator images. Basically I want to be able to say inside my build.gradle

```
emulator{
   image=android-18
   memory=1024
   resolution=x y
   window=yes/no
}
```

and have Gradle download the original image and set it up like specified.

Is there some plugin that can do things like this?

NOTE:I know that there are CI plugins like this Jenkins one https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin
but that is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a pure Gradle solution, which will auto manage emulator state for testing and running the app on developers machines.

Comment: try this: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Comment: try https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html and add your *.bat file to gradle.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question since I don't see any relevant info on that page. I know you can specify which task to run from console but I am looking for a Gradle plugin that will give me tasks like gradle startEmulator, gradle stopEmulator, gradle setupEmulator or something like that. Also I don't get the *.bat file reference, bat scripts are not platform agnostic and I would have to write the scripts themselves and call them using exec task in gradle anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible solutions:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/test/gradle-managed-devices: official supported in AGP
- https://github.com/quittle/gradle-android-emulator: looks quite good.
- https://github.com/gocal/android-emulator-plugin: looks old and deprecated

Comment: I am the author of the first project listed and created it specifically for that purposes of being a Gradle-native solution for managing the emulator lifecycle so you could just run `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` without worrying about getting your system in the right state

Answer (score 0):

This is now available from Google:
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#gmd